# Check if Google IdToken has expired

Tags: android, google-authentication, google-signin

Is there a way to determine whether an IdToken provided after authentication via a Google signIn in an app has expired ? Now I saw some posts here in S.O mentioning 1 hour of validity, others talk about a "random" time i.e in their app users got logged out at some point in time. I've tried to look at the official documentation but I can't see anything which officially talks about the 1 hour validity for the IdToken. So how can I determine whether or not the token is still valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information about validating a Google issued ID token here [1].

Specifically on Android, this blog [2] shows you how to validate ID tokens.

[1] https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#validatinganidtoken

[2] https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html